# How do I fetch an image url to display it on a RecyclerView item using Retrofit?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview, retrofit2

I'm currently learning about APIs, Retrofit and LiveData in Kotlin and I can't figure out how to fetch an image to then display it to the `RecyclerView` item `ImageView`.
This is my Retrofit `interface` :

```
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.*

interface ApiService {
    @Headers("Authorization: token 123")
    @GET("search/users")
    fun getUsers(
        @Query("q") query: String
    ): Call<GithubResponse>
}
```

This is my `RecyclerView` item layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv_users"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="85dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_users"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        tools:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_users"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/iv_users"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/iv_users" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm currently working on making the `Adapter` for the `RecyclerView` which is currently like this to get the `text` :

```
class UsersAdapter(private val listUsers: List<String>): RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(viewGroup: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
        ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.context).inflate(R.layout.item_users, viewGroup, false))

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        viewHolder.tvUser.text = listUsers[position]
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = listUsers.size

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        val tvUser: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_users)
    }
}
```

And finally this is my data Class :

```
data class GithubResponse(

    @field:SerializedName("total_count")
    val totalCount: Int,

    @field:SerializedName("incomplete_results")
    val incompleteResults: Boolean,

    @field:SerializedName("items")
    val items: List<ItemsItem>
)

data class ItemsItem(

    @field:SerializedName("gists_url")
    val gistsUrl: String,

    @field:SerializedName("repos_url")
    val reposUrl: String,

    @field:SerializedName("following_url")
    val followingUrl: String,

    @field:SerializedName("starred_url")
    val starredUrl: String,

    @field:SerializedName("login")
    val login: String,

    @field:SerializedName("followers_url")
    val followersUrl: String,

    @field:SerializedName("type")
    val type: String,

    @field:SerializedName("url")
    val url: String,

    @field:SerializedName("subscriptions_url")
    val subscriptionsUrl: String,

    @field:SerializedName("score")
    val score: Any,

    @field:SerializedName("received_events_url")
    val receivedEventsUrl: String,

    @field:SerializedName("avatar_url")
    val avatarUrl: String,

    @field:SerializedName("events_url")
    val eventsUrl: String,

    @field:SerializedName("html_url")
    val htmlUrl: String,

    @field:SerializedName("site_admin")
    val siteAdmin: Boolean,

    @field:SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int,

    @field:SerializedName("gravatar_id")
    val gravatarId: String,

    @field:SerializedName("node_id")
    val nodeId: String,

    @field:SerializedName("organizations_url")
    val organizationsUrl: String
)
```

How do I fetch the image url from the data class? (`avatarUrl`)

Answer (score 1):

Use an image loading library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), or [Coil](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/).

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestion! I was also looking it up and thought about using Glide. Can you help me with that?

Comment: "Can you help me with that?" - Sure.

Comment: Well I'm sorry if I offend you, it's just that I'm new to the Android Development world and I'm trying to learn as much as I can because frankly enough, I didn't find many documentation on my particular case. I was just wondering if you have any suggestions on how to use Glide in Kotlin since I've never used it.

Comment: I was not offended. You asked a vague question so I gave a vague answer. Am I supposed to know what you need? I already provided the link to Glide which has documentation on how to use it. Have you read it? Have you tried anything? Is there something you're stuck on? If I told you "hey, I want to build a house, can you help me with that?" wouldn't you need slightly more information? I'm happy to help but you need to clarify what it is you actually need help with. Help me help you.